# Plumier - parameters property null when accessed inside custom validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I have a custom validation that access `parameter` property of `context` but the value is always `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```js
function isValidVersion() {
    return val.custom(async (val, i) => {
        const appIdIdx = i.route.action.parameters.findIndex(x => x.name === "appId")
        if (appIdIdx === -1)
            throw new Error(`No appId parameter found in ${i.route.controller.name}.${i.route.action.name}`)
        const appId = i.ctx.parameters![appIdIdx] //<--- the parameters is undefined

        //other code
        //
    })
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parameters` value only available after the validation process done, since it is populated with cleansed/validated value.

So yes, you can't access `parameters` property during validation process.

FYI `parameters` property is just a list of value extracted from http context value such as `query`, `headers` or `body`. As a workaround, you can access the raw data of the parameters from the `ctx` property, such as `ctx.request.query` or `ctx.request.body`.

For example if the `appId` extracted from your query URL your code will be simply:

```js
function isValidVersion() {
    return val.custom(async (val, i) => {
        const appId = i.ctx.request.query.appid
        if (!appId)
            throw new Error(`No appId parameter found in ${i.route.controller.name}.${i.route.action.name}`)

        //other code
        //
    })
}
```